# Bless hex editor - offset show

Tags: hex, editor

How can I change the offset default from hexadecimal to decimal in the Bless hex editor?
I have tried all the settings but nothing!

Answer (score 1):

Simply click on "Offset" at the bottom of the Bless main window; doing this repeatedly you can toggle between decimal, octal and hexadecimal.